# Yii2 - Different persistent login cookie on same domain

Tags: yii2, yii2-user

I have a domain that has 2 different installs of YII2, lets call them old and new site.  If I login to the old site and ask to be remembered, then close the browser and then later go to the new sites login page, I am logged in to new site and it takes me to a dashboard.

I looked at changing the cookieValidationKey in web.php

```
    'request' => [
        // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
        'cookieValidationKey' => 'thisisthenewsitekey',
    ],
```

and I looked around the whole request setup but I can't see anything.

Is there a way to separate the 2 logins cookies, so if I'm logged in on old site, I'm not also logged in on new site?

Comment: so did you actually change the cookieValidationKey? It should solve your problem.

Comment: I did.  I tried it just now for sanities sake and I'm logged in on the newsite and I went to the old site and I am also logged in with the same user there, even though I've not logged into the old site for months and definitely not with that account, as it's specific to the new site.

Answer (score 0):

Add to config file:

```
'session' => [
    // this is the name of the session cookie used for login
    'name' => 'site2',
    'cookieParams' => [
        'path' => 'yourPath..',
    ],
],
```

(Optional) Also you can do, for `csrfParam` and `identityCookie`

If you use a shared domain or Cross-subdomain authentication:

```
$config = [
    // ...
    'components' => [
        // ...
        'user' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\User',
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'loginUrl' => '/user/login',
            'identityCookie' => [ // <---- here!
                'name' => '_identity',
                'httpOnly' => true,
                'domain' => '.example.com',
            ],
        ],
        'request' => [
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'your_validation_key'
        ],
        'session' => [
            'cookieParams' => [
                'domain' => '.example.com',
                'httpOnly' => true,
            ],
        ],

    ],
];
```